# SQLite3 Reference Errors

Tags: swift, sqlite

After inserting SQLite.xcodeproj into my current iOS project, in addition to adding the SQLite.framework, I borrowed code from [here](https://www.raywenderlich.com/123579/sqlite-tutorial-swift) - to be more specific, `sqlite3_close(dbPointer)` `sqlite3_open(path, &db)` and `sqlite3_close(db)`. However, when I build and run the app, I get a handful of errors which I don't understand because I assume that I included everything. [Click here to see a screenshot of the errors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aVKuH.png).

Comment: did you `import SQLite`

Comment: Yes sir, that's why I'm so baffled

Answer (score 0):

**Update:** After tinkering around, I discovered that if you go to Build Phases > Link Binary With Libraries and add libsql3.tbd, the errors will vanish.